# Display data from database with space in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to show data from my database, but with space in it? I have data "6285398980808" on my database, but i want to show it like "62 853 9898 0808".
Any suggestion greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's your straucture for seprate?

Comment: Is all data which you want is in `6285398980808` format?

Comment: @paranoid what do you mean? If You mean that what I've worked, here some my code

$b="select * from `tb_dinilai`";
$display=mysql_query($b);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($display);

$nip2=$row['nip_dinilai'];

echo $nip2;

Comment: are you seprate all data like this 00 000 0000 0000?

Comment: @AjayMakwana I want to show it as 62 853 9898 0808 (with space)

Comment: @paranoid I don't know how to separate the data, that's my question

Comment: Can you provide us with the field names of the fields in your `tb_dinilai` table? Are you only interested in the `nip_dinilai` field?

Comment: 13 Digits fixed?? always u got 13 digits..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your number fixed as 13 digits number than you can use `preg_replace()` as:

```
<?php
//62 853 9898 0808 required
$number = 6285398980808;

$formatted_number = preg_replace("/^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{4})$/", "$1 $2 $3 $4", $number);
echo $formatted_number; // 62 853 9898 0808
?>
```

Comment: It's working, i can use it for other separate format too

Comment: @AndityaPratama: ahan, best of luck bro... happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

There is a special function for that [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) - just play with parameters.

Comment: The OP's request for formatting is not separated in thousands.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CONCAT_WS(' ', SUBSTR(str, 1, 2), SUBSTR(str, 3, 3), SUBSTR(str, 6, 4), SUBSTR(str, 10, 4))` in your `SELECT` statement. Just replace 'str' with the name of the field.

If the field name is `nip_dinilai` and your table name is `tb_dinilai`then the query will look like this :

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', SUBSTR(nip_dinilai, 1, 2), SUBSTR(nip_dinilai, 3, 3), SUBSTR(nip_dinilai, 6, 4), SUBSTR(nip_dinilai, 10, 4)) AS nip_dinilai FROM tb_dinilai
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [number_format():](http://php.net/number_format)

number_format — Format a number with grouped thousands

Comment: The OP's request for formatting is not separated in thousands.